# Holding off on it or Holding it off or Holding off of it?

Tags: idioms, word-usage, phrasal-verbs

I would like to say that I'm pausing / postponing work on something.

I wasn't sure which of the following is the right way to say it:

1. I'm holding off on it for the time being
2. I'm holding off of it for the time being
3. I'm holding it off for the time being
4. I'm holding off working on it for the time being
5. None of the above, if so what's the "right" way to say it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiom is: "Hold off on," your first one is correct. I've always found that remarkably clunky and difficult to understand if taken piece by piece, however.

You could try "Putting something into a holding pattern" or "Hold fast on something for a time" to preserve some of the vocabulary, or switch to "We aren't moving forward on that right now" or "That's been tabled for the time being."

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the first one is correct. 'I'm holding off on something' means a very specific something. e.g. 'I'm holding off from telling him the truth of what happened in case it upsets him'.

I think you would need to use number 4.

But why is this better than saying simply 'I'm postponing work on the project for the time being'?